# Exclusion in search

Tags: java, search, grep

I'm trying to search in my documents for a space character that isn't preceded by a comma. (That is, I want to search " " but that's not ", ".) I know, this is very specific, but, does grep or some other tool offer this? (I'm not particular about the editor, I'd just like to know if this can be done. I also know a bit of Java, if anyone knows how to do this inside of a method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abc def, ghi klm";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,] ");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    int count = 0;
    while (m.find())
        count++;

    System.out.println(count); //prints 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a regex to search, `[^,]\s` should work for you